# Prove that in $\triangle ABC$ ,$QP\parallel BC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image: My diagram]
In the triangle $\triangle ABC$ , the point $M$ is between $B$ and $C$. And also the lines $MP$ and $MQ$ are bisectors of $\angle AMC$ and  $\angle AMB$. It means that: $$\angle AMP=\angle PMC$$

$$\angle AMQ=\angle QMB$$
and
$$BM=MC$$
So now the puzzle tells us to prove that:$$QP\parallel BC$$
So I know Thales's theorem and all relations between the similiar triangles. But I can't find any pairs of similiar triangles or any parallel lines to use the Thales's theorem!
Please help me proving $QP\parallel BC$.

Comment: Dumb question possibly, but I just want to clarify. You initially say $M$ is just between $B,C$, but then later act as if it is the midpoint of the segment and act as if the lines from $P,Q$ to $M$ are bisectors of their respective angles. I just want to make sure that these latter facts (midpoint, angle bisectors) are, indeed, given since your wording is vague in this respect.

Answer (score 4):

By the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), $$\frac{AQ}{QB}=\frac{AM}{MB}\text{ and }\frac{AP}{PC}=\frac{AM}{MC}\,.$$
Since $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$, we have $MB=MC$, whence
$$\frac{AQ}{QB}=\frac{AP}{PC}\,.$$
Therefore, $PQ\parallel BC$.

Comment: This might be a silly question but how did you reach the last conclusion? I mean from $$\frac{AQ}{QB} = \frac{AP}{PC}$$ to $PQ || BC$

Comment: See https://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/similar/triangles/side-splitter-theorem.php.  I used the converse of the Side-Splitter Theorem.  Theorem 4.3 here also states and proves the converse: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/MATH7200/Sect4.1.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot Batominovski! But only a small problem! Did you draw a line from P to C ? Actually I don't see PC in my diagram!

Comment: @user602338  What do you mean you don't see $PC$ in your diagram?  In your diagram, you have $P$ on the side $AC$.

Comment: You have written PC in your proof above. Don't you?

Comment: Yes, and what about it?

Comment: Ohh no! Have you edited your answer? I had taken a picture from previous one!

Comment: There was a typo at some point, and I edited it.

Comment: Ok thanks! Do you have any other ideas to prove it? I mean using any other theorem to prove it?

Comment: Not really.  I can prove the statement with a more advanced method, like using a homothety, but the solution written above is the simplest I know.  If you want that solution, then let $N$ be the point on the ray $AM$ such that $M$ lies between $A$ and $N$, and that $MN=MB=MC$.  Take $h$ to be the homothety about $A$ that sends $M$ to $N$.  Prove that $h$ sends $PQ$ to $BC$, whence $PQ\parallel BC$.